# Calling methods on React-Leaflet components (LayerGroup)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, kml, react-leaflet

I am trying to call the method `toGeoJSON` on my React-Leaflet LayerGroup. 
(Ultimately I am trying to convert the layer group into KML, but I found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159344/export-to-kml-option-using-leaflet), and I am first trying to convert it into geoJSON)

I tried adding a `ref` to the LayerGroup and then calling `toGeoJSON` on it, but it fails as that is not a function. When inspecting the `ref` for the LayerGroup, it doesn't seem to have any of the methods available in the [leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layergroup)

Is there a way around this? I have Leaflet and ReactLeaflet libraries imported and in scope of the function, I'm just not sure how to find that function.

Simplified version of my code:

```
function MyMap(){
  const markerRef = useRef()

  function export(){
    let markers = markerRef.current
    let GeoJSON = markers.toGeoJSON() // < THIS LINE THROWS AN ERROR
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={export}>Export</button>
      <Map>
        <LayerGroup ref={this.markersRef}>{markers}</LayerGroup>
      </Map>
    </>
  )
}
```

More thorough example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lealfet-map-bug-report-4258z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to access `markers.leafletElement.toGeoJSON()`. Leaflet methods can be accessed through `leafletElement`.

oops